# How to create Read only Connection in Java for Oracle Database

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have  to design a tool which having text area where user can enter the their query and by giving submitting results will be shown. My requirement is such a way that it should accept only select queries but not update, insert, delete. If it is select results should be shown, otherwise error should be thrown. I have tried as below to make DB connection read only.

Connection.setReadOnly(true) which is not recommendable and its throwing an error.

'setReadOnly' is not supported on WebSphere java.sql.Connection implementation.

Can some one please help me in getting Read only connection for Database or if any design changes are needed

Comment: relevant question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310808/spring-readonly-transaction-with-propagation-supports-with-websphere-and-oracle

Answer (score 6):

A common concept is to give the DB-User only the grants that are needed.
In your case the application could use an application-specific user with select-grants on the allowed tables / views.

To clarify some misunderstandings: I am talking about the user your JDBC-Connection works with.

Comment: this is **definitely the better approach** then programmatically handle queries... we're working with java and DBs and any other idea is rather scaring!

Comment: Another approach, and widely used is to create specific ROLES. For example, in test environment we give SUPER-USER role to all the application developers. But, in production, we only give READ-ONLY role. The most important part is to build the mechanism to grant the required ROLES to the APPLICATION USERS.

Comment: it's the same approach @LalitKumarB, just a refined form of... you can grant rights for users or give users certain roles (roles wich have different rights)...

Comment: Certainly. I being a database guy, said it the way I look at the approach.

Comment: same here - i think it good to mention the different aspects of user administartion on DBs - thanks for submitting such help!!!

Answer (score 5):

You can create a read only user in the following way :

```
SQL> create user read_only identified by read_only;

User created.

SQL> grant create session, select any table, select any dictionary to read_only;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn read_only@pdborcl/read_only;
Connected.
SQL> create table t(col number);
create table t(col number)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


SQL> desc scott.emp;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EMPNO                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(10)
 JOB                                                VARCHAR2(9)
 MGR                                                NUMBER(4)
 HIREDATE                                           DATE
 SAL                                                NUMBER(7,2)
 COMM                                               NUMBER(7,2)
 DEPTNO                                             NUMBER(2)

SQL> select count(*) from scott.emp;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14

SQL> update scott.emp set ename='LALIT';
update scott.emp set ename='LALIT'
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


SQL> insert into scott.emp(ename) values('LALIT');
insert into scott.emp(ename) values('LALIT')
                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks Lalit le me try this

Answer (score -1):

If you absolutely must make the user type the query rather than give them a gui query builder, you can get the query string and before actually executing it through the entity manager, you can do a simple check for key words like

```
if (QueryString.toLowerCase().contains("update"))// to be case insensitive
{//handle as you wish}
else if (QueryString.toLowerCase().contains("delete"))// to be case insensitive
{//handle as you wish} // Keep doing that as many times as you with till finally
else
{// Execute your query}
```

Thats a very quick and dirty solution if your really stuck

Comment: quick, dirty and dangerous. `SELECT t.lastUpdated from DELETES_TABLE` won't work although it's a select.

Comment: oh well, & that too ... never mind, scratch that idea. Sometimes I look at my answers and think what the hell was I thinking when I wrote that. Also what kind of user would agree to writes sql these days? (or CAN for that matter),I am having trouble explaining to clients that a our application has SSO and there is no need for login from windows. We almost lost their account when some top mgmt idiot opened the app on his ipad infront of his client and saw the login screen for the first time. He tried everything except his windows credentials including a childhood hotmail account he had